# Changing or removing command linked to a button after clicking

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Playing around with Tkinter and ran into some trouble. 
I have 3 buttons:

Button1 will open my specified website using Selenium.

Button3 will carry out my function on the website.

Button2 will close the program.

```
Problem: I want to keep button1 from opening multiple windows/websites by 
either removing/hiding it after it has been clicked or changing the 
command 
that will be performed by it.



   After some googling I found some options and tried the following:
   | pack_forget()
   | pack_destroy()
   | btn1.destroy()
```

All of the above does not seem to be doing anything. What am I missing?

```
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from time import sleep
    import time
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import *

    main = Tk()

    def Primary():
        txt = mtxt.get()
        New = Label(main, text=""+txt, fg='Blue').pack(side=BOTTOM)
        btn1 = Button(Bot, text='OK', command=Primary, 
        fg='Green').pack_destroy() #For some reason this does not work
        return

    def Secondary():
        global main
        main.destroy()

    def Tres():
        txt = mtxt.get()
        New = Label(main, text=""+txt, fg='Blue').pack(side=BOTTOM)
        return

    main.geometry('350x400+500+300')
    main.title('Title')

    mtxt = StringVar()

    Top = Frame().pack()
    Bot = Frame().pack(side=BOTTOM)

    Lbl = Label(main, text='TEXT').pack()
    Lbl2 = Label(main, text='TEXT').pack()

    Enter = Entry(main, textvariable=mtxt).pack()

    btn1 = Button(Bot, text='OK', command=Primary, fg='Green').pack()
    btn2 = Button(Bot, text='Cancel', command=Secondary, 
    fg='Red').pack(side=BOTTOM)
    btn3 = Button(Bot, text='Next', command=Tres, fg='Green').pack()

    main.mainloop()
```

Expected result:
On initial click btn1 performs 'command=Primary'

After initial click btn1 performs 'command=Tres'

or

after initial click btn1 is destroyed/hidden and btn3 takes it's place.

Comment: `pack_destroy` is not a command, which is why it doesn't work. Did you get that from some documentation?

Comment: Hi Bryan tx for the quick response. Im using bits and pieces from forums/websites the specific example was: btn1.destroy() from a reddit page. After failing multiple times I just started randomly combining pack,btn1 and destroy in hope that something will work.... Basically none of the examples worked and just followed the Primary command

Comment: randomly guessing at code isn't a good path for learning.

Comment: I guess frustration got the best of me. Any ideas on how I could hide/remove btn1 after clicking? The examples online is either very confusing or not working.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that button1 will open a website and perform the action required. Button2 will only perform the action on the website without opening the website again.